# cant stop mysql server and cant start it as well

Tags: mysql

Not sure what is happening, I try to stop and get this:

```
~ » sudo mysql.server stop                                                                                                                                                           
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

and try to start and get this:

```
~ » sudo mysql.server start                                                                                                                                                          
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/John-MBP-2.pid).
```

so lost...

Comment: `sudo kill -TERM <pid>`

Comment: Is it actually running, or did it crash? Try `ps -ef | grep -i mysql`. Do you get any process?

Comment: @TheImpaler cant find the pid :\ tried ```ps aux | grep mysqld``` but something weird is happening there, i run it once and saw one result' run it again saw 3 result...something weird and non of the ids there work when i try to kill

Comment: Sometimes mysql server gets screwed up. You could try backing the mysql directory up, unloading launch agent, deleting the directory, restarting your system, starting mysql, moving backup back. I had an unresponsive mysql some weeks ago and it was a screwed up PID file. After deleting and letting the system recreating it, everything worked.

Comment: @TheImpaler after running in now few times got this line ```myusernam        83444   0.0  0.0  4278276    728 s002  R+   10:08PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql```. and when run the kill on 83444 i got ```kill: 83444: No such process```

Comment: I suspect your system has already one instance running and is unable to start another one. Check user + system launch agent launch deamon directories.

Comment: @SEJU yes it seams this way but dont know what to check other than that."Check user + system launch agent launch deamon directories" what do you mean here?

Comment: In my case I have mysql installed through brew. Somehow I ended up with launch plists in /library/launchagents + users/myaccount/library/launchagent (or deamon). After deleting one and restarting mysql started just fine.

Comment: @SEJU i upgraded to with brew before, now when i switched back with ```brew switch mysql 5.7.20_1``` my mysql back to work...but i wanted to use higher version :/

Comment: probably pid + log files are not compatible. I switched back to 5.7.21 after installing mysql 8 and discovering that my mysql gems did not work.